# EF Code First creates more foreign keys than expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I'm working on an application that should be able to switch between code first and database first, so I took the code generated by EF (from db first) and tried to create code first. In the end, the databases were the same, except this `Activity` table that besides `TypeId` and `SubTypeId` contains also `Type_Id` and `Type_Id1` both nullable and I don't understand why.

```
public class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public int? SubTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
    public virtual Type Type { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubTypeId")]
    public virtual Type Type1 { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: try removing the virtual keyword before your annoted navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below will work for you

```
  public class Activity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Type")]
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Type1")]
        public int? SubTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual Type Type { get; set; }

        public virtual Type Type1 { get; set; }
    }
```